# Is there a way to target the first element of @page using css

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I have a pdf, I have multiple pages on it. I have removed the margin/padding from all the pages using:

```
@page {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0cm;
    margin-bottom: 1cm;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I did this so I can have my `h2` sit at the top right close to the edges. (My h2s have a background).

But as a result of that, pages that don't have an h2 in the start, start right from the edge of the page.

**Is there a way for me to style the first element of every page using the @page selector so that it takes some spacing top by default?**

Ideally I want to do something like:

```
@page *:first-child {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

P.S: I also tried having a page margin/padding by default, but then no matter what I did, I was not able to take my `h2` close to the edge. If there's a way to do that, then let me know, that will also fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting negative margin-top to your h2?

Comment: Yup, that and top: -40px, and the h2 shifts up, but if the page has a margin/padding, the h2 doesn't go near the edge, rather it actually goes to the previous page.

Comment: what if you put page-break-before the h2? https://printcss.live/gl9avgrbG1

Comment: already have that, page-break-before: always;
But that does not remove the header from the page.